# Wordpress media library - image thumbnails missing

Tags: wordpress, media-library

I have moved a website from the preview environment to production.
All images display correctly on the front facing elements, however if I login to the admin area and look in media library I see no thumbnails.

I have tried several plugins to rebuild those thumbnails but they do not work.

It appears to be an issue with the database, maybe it is pointing to a physical file location.

Could anybody suggest any ways to resolve this?

Comment: check deactivating all the plugins or check the media image url is corrupted.

Comment: I have 3 suggestions:
1. install Force regenerate thumbnails
2.  repair database (via plugin or cpanel)
3. Move all your images to one folder in wp-uploads and see if it helps

Comment: Do you use http or https? Using chrome dev tool to find what the thumbnail path is.